# How to run GJS (meson) project from terminal?

Tags: gtk, gnome, meson-build, gjs

I'm trying to learn programming in GJS and meson. I've generated GJS project using Gnome Builder. Because Gnome Builder is not suitable for me, I would like to use other IDE like VS Code or IntelliJ IDEA.

How can I run the project from terminal? Also, is there any tutorial about how to integrate GJS with other IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/gcampax/gtk-js-app/issues/15#issuecomment-508499598), to run GJS app with meson from terminal we need to
make the following commands. All command should be performed from root project of the app.

1. Set up prefix. In root folder of the project run `meson --prefix $PWD/install build`. As I understand the folder will contain build of the app (it's kind of instalation folder) which we will run later on (correct me if I'm wrong).
2. Build and install the app. `ninja -C build install`. Now you can check out what's inside of 'install' folder.
3. Run the app .`/install/bin/com.example.Gtk.JSApplication`